# Call rails function onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

In my ruby on rails project, I have a form with a group of sliders that look like this:

```
<%= range_field(:subproject, :ans1, in: 0..100, id: 'slider1', :class => 'range range--light', :'data-init' => 'auto', :step => 1, :value => $project_value_1.to_i) %>
```

The total values of the sliders should always be equal to 100 fo rthe form to be submittable. Otherwise, an error message is displayed. All that is handled by this function:

```
$sumOfProjectValues = $project_value_1.to_i + $project_value_2.to_i + $project_value_3.to_i + $project_value_4.to_i + $project_value_5.to_i

          if $sumOfProjectValues == 100
              message = 'Project can be saved'
              btnStyle = 'confirmation'
              hideDisabled = 'none'
            else
              message = 'Project quota must add up to 100% before saving'
              btnStyle = 'alert'
              hideEnabled = 'none'
            end
```

I would like to call this form validation function everytime a value changes (sort of like the onChange method in JS). 
How do I do this?

Comment: Do you actually want this to happen within the Rails code or within a JS (Validation syntax looks like Ruby but you're talking about JS onChange)?

Comment: @wiesion I would prefer rails. Ruby doesn't have an onChange method, though. That would be ideal and that's why I mentioned it.

Comment: I think you need to take a closer look at [ActiveRecord Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) - you can implement your 100% check as a Validator. If it doesn't pass, the object can't be persisted and you can deliver an error message.

Comment: @wiesion¨iS that the only/easiest way? Because that's a pain in the rear end

Comment: Not sure what is so painful about validators, it is certainly the most rails and clean way to validate data before persisting it. If you're validating only in JS, you would still have the possibility do deactivate JS and send invalid data. In my eyes, client side realtime validation is a goodie, but server side validation is a must.

Comment: @wiesion If I interpreted what I have read so far correctly, validation using helpers isn't resonsive either. Literally all I want is the second snipplet to run, when a slider's value changes.

Answer (score 0):

try code:

```
$(".range").onChange(function(){
  var sumOfProjectValues = $project_value_1.to_i + $project_value_2.to_i +    $project_value_3.to_i + $project_value_4.to_i + $project_value_5.to_i

          if sumOfProjectValues == 100
              alert('Project can be saved')
          else
              alert('Project quota must add up to 100% before saving')
          end
})
```

Comment: Doesn't work. (I fixed the syntax errors but it doesn't do anything)

Comment: @JustusP try `change` instead of `onChange`

Comment: That won't change anything. The values are ruby variables. You can't just call them in JS.

Comment: you can add ruby variable in js variables eg `var a = "<%= b%>"`

Comment: Good point! I did that but now I get `Uncaught TypeError: ".range".onChange is not a function`

Comment: try change instead of onChange

Comment: The error is gone, but it doesn't do anything. Code: https://pastebin.com/fPuWPqQ3

Comment: I think your change function is not fired

Comment: add `alert("test")` below `$(".range").change(function(){`

Comment: You're right. That does nothing either. Is the function not called by the `$(".range").change(...` part?

Comment: add jquery cdn url to page..I think jquery is not included

Comment: jQuery rails gem is installed. If it weren't, console would log an error.

Comment: or try `$(".range").on('change', function(){ ... })`